# forge mod block textures 1.12

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am creating a new block in minecraft but in 1.12 it puts me a new error loading the texture

```
[12:00:20] [main/ERROR] [FML]: Exception loading model for variant 
chestadd:chestone#facing=west for blockstate 
"chestadd:chestone[facing=west]"
net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry$LoaderException: 
Exception loading model chestadd:chestone#facing=west with loader 
VariantLoader.INSTANCE, skipping
... 
Caused by: net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.
ModelBlockDefinition$MissingVariantException
```

my assets.{MODID}.blockstates

```
{
    "variants": {
        "normal": {
            "model": "chestadd:chestone"
        }
    }
}
```

my assets.{MODID}.models.block

```
{
    "parent": "block/cube",
    "textures": {
        "down": "chestadd:blocks/ChestOneBottom",
        "up": "chestadd:blocks/ChestOneTop",
        "north": "chestadd:blocks/ChestOne1",
        "east": "chestadd:blocks/ChestOne2",
        "south": "chestadd:blocks/ChestOne3",
        "west": "chestadd:blocks/ChestOne4"
    }
}
```

And my assets.{MODID}.models.item

```
{
    "parent": "chestone:block/chestone"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`"chestadd:blocks/ChestOneBottom"`

## Assets must be all lower case.

Comment: And if that doesn't solve it, you need to post more of your log. You only posted the surface error. The next line should start with `Caused by...` and contain useful information.